# How do i refer my database or point to that specific UID?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm doing a simple Blog Apps. 
as Coded below when I clcik on the Like button, it refers to all the Child and does not show the specific ID's likes. need help please. 
All I want is when the user click the Like button, it should auto count and replace the text like.. 0 like, 2 likes, 3 likes. etc and so on.. 
This is how i want to refer to my database.

This is my Database Image.

[image]

```
   mDatabaseLike.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


           // cant find the solution here.. :D

                    if(dataSnapshot.hasChild(post_key)){
                        int count = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                        holder.updateLikeCount(count);

                    }else{

                        holder.updateLikeCount(0);
                    }


                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

And here it will replace and Update my Likes at my BlogViewHolder class.

```
 public void updateLikeCount(int count){
        blogLikeCount = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_like_count);
        blogLikeCount.setText(count +" Likes");

    }
```

Comment: So you want to count all childrens beneah `Liked by` node, right? In this case 3?

Comment: yes. bro.. i finally found it out..
        mDatabaseLike.child(post_id). etc etc etc... hahah.. thanks.. so simple..

Comment: can you please answer your own question so others can also get helped ?thanks